# Does SQLite have an auto-deletion feature in an in-memory database?

Tags: sqlite, in-memory-database, in-memory

I want to start using an in-memory database with an auto-deletion feature enabled and set for a couple hours.

I have a huge volume of data and requirements to support different types of complex queries (just for data persisted on last one or two hours).

I believe that in-memory databases can help me with that. And SQLite is very well adopted and trusted. And it has a in-memory feature. But, I didn't find anything about an auto-deletion feature (based on time).

I see that auto-deletion is a common feature on in-memory databases (i.e., IMDB), but I didn't find a SQLite documentation about it.

I want to have some feedback/direction from the community with more experience with in-memory databases.

Thanks.

Comment: Include a timestamp column in your tables. Periodically delete anything older than a given time.

Answer (score -2):

Full disclosure: I work for the vendor.  eXtremeDB (an in-memory database system available since 2001) has a time-to-live (TTL) feature. It can be expressed either in terms of the maximum number of rows to be stored for a table, or the amount of elapsed time after which a row is purged (but only when a new row comes in). There are non-SQL and SQL APIs available.